# video-streaming over lan

Tags: c#, video-streaming

I have a main server which will be reproducing videos or running an application on it.
My application has to capture the output of anything that runs on the server, and display it live
on several pcs over the network. The pcs over the network will be running another application (developed by me) which will be showing different content (from flash to videos (this part is already done)), but, when the streaming from the server start, I will stop that reproduction and start showing the content that comes from the server.

I'm trying to do this in c# 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010.
Any ideas of what can I do or where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has always been my network streaming tool of choice - there is also a C# library available (although I haven't used it) http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=58438